# Single Engine Rating

Tags: single-engine

I am CPL(A) holder with MEP(land) and IR rating. I need to make extra hours to build up my hours on my logbook. However, I was thinking if this would be possible on a single engine without having a SEP rating? Is it possible to fly SE with a flight instructor as an education flight or so and not having the SEP rating or do I have to get a SEP rating?

Comment: What country's rules are you asking about?

Comment: ICAO licensed countries. Middle east and Asia region. I asked to many schools and each time I get a different answer. Some say you can fly dual with a flight instructor and some say that is absolutely not allowed without having the rating, because that will only give you a flight experience without the hours counting.

Comment: If you are MEP rated, the SEP rating should be quite simple of an endeavor.  I would just go and get it.

Comment: You can't just say "ICAO licensed countries" because every country has slightly different rules. For example that I'm familiar with, Australia and New Zealand are two very similar countries, yet NZ doesn't even have a concept of a SEP rating (every aircraft is type-rated there).

Comment: Wbeard52 thank you for your answer and motivation. I guess I will just get it indeed. 

@Ben thank you for your answer as well. My apologies, I will be more specific. I asked some schools and countries like Egypt, Indonesia and India. For myself Im based in Indonesia and each school and flight instructor tells me a different answer.